# Syntax error in model and controller after setting up Paperclip Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm burning through the onemonthrails tutorial. And I've just installed the paperclip gem and set up the model with some validations. I thought I followed the tut exactly but when I go into the localhost:3000/pins I get this weird syntax error that points to both the model and the controller. I didn't have this problem before the paperclip install...

Here's the error:

```
SyntaxError (C:/Sites/code/omrails/app/models/pin.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected

'}', expecting tASSOC):

app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

Here's the github branch, if you go into the master you can see the code before I installed paperclip (when it was working fine):

https://github.com/justuseapen/omrails/tree/error

EDIT Here's the offending code from the model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base


    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true
                                                                content_type: {content_type['image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png','image/gif']}
                                                                size: {less_than: 5.megabytes }
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, styles: {medium:"320x240"}

end
```

And from the controller:

```
   class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new


  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
    @pin=current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    @pin=current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin=current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

SOLUTION:

Ok. So I'm not sure what the problem was, but I rewrote the code like so and it worked:

```
    validates :description, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                            content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                            size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Comment: You need to post the code here, not a link to your repo.

Comment: also, better to post the code after it's broken - working code is hard to debug :p

Comment: The error branch is the broken code. The working code is in the master from a previous commit. I've included the broken here though as well.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Yeah I posted the solution at the bottom of the questioon

Answer (score 2):

You have a comma where there shouldn't be one.

```
validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
```

should be

```
validates_attachment :image, presence: true
```

Comment: I removed the comma but that just gave me another error:

SyntaxError (C:/Sites/code/omrails/app/models/pin.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected
 ':', expecting keyword_end

                                                content_type: {content_type['ima
ge/jpeg','...

                                                             ^
C:/Sites/code/omrails/app/models/pin.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecti
ng tASSOC):
  app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:9:in `index'

Comment: Also, the commas are included in the tutorial so I'm really confused now.

Answer (score 1):

```
validates_attachment :image, presence: true
```

w\o ','

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntactical errors per [the documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) on validation. You should be passing an array of strings to your `content_type` validation:

```
content_type: ['image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/png','image/gif']
```